# Access denied PDO Exception - other users are getting it but not me

Tags: database, debugging

I've set up a new Drupal 7 site (which is still in a vanilla post-install state with no custom code, no themes, no content). This particular site runs on a remote DB, with users (my team colleagues) downloading the Drupal code from a VCS to run on their local machines. Everyone is getting the following error while trying to access the site - **except me.** I can log into the site just fine.

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 
'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in lock_may_be_available() 
(line 167 of /private/var/www/drupal_media_7/includes/lock.inc).
```

What could be different about my local setup, given that we should all be running the same code and accessing the same database with the same credentials? (since the credentials are all in the code).

How might I start debugging this?

Comment: I don't know how to debug it as well.. but you can check if [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981618/mysql-server-has-gone-away-in-drupal-7) help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have them check sites/default/settings.php and see if the credentials for your database user (assuming 'root') are correct.

If it is, they should also be checking to see if:

1. The user 'root' has access to the local database and
2. Root has that same password as an sql user

Comment: Thanks for this - somehow the sites/thingybob/settings.php had ended up pointing to a local database on my machine rather than the remote database. So no wonder I was the only one who could get in. Accepting your answer as it made me go back and check the Drupal settings files.